# Cannot set registry insert for HKLM for 32-bit

Tags: registry, contextmenu, inno-setup, explorer, windows-shell

I want to create a context menu with sub menu items in Inno-setup.
The problem is, is that it inserts HKLM keys in the 64-bit registry (WoW6432Node) section.

The [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode) states that if the 64-bit architecture is not specified, the setup is running in 32-bit mode.
[Modes](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode)

```
[Registry]
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "folder\shell\TestMenu"; ValueType: string; Flags: UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "folder\shell\TestMenu"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MUIVerb"; ValueData: "test menu"; Flags: deletevalue UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "folder\shell\TestMenu"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SubCommands"; ValueData: "Testmenu.sub1;Testmenu.sub2"; Flags: deletevalue UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Testmenu.sub1"; ValueType: string; Flags: UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Testmenu.sub1"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "Sub menu 1"; Flags: deletevalue UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Testmenu.sub1\command"; ValueType: string; ValueData: ""; Flags: deletevalue UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Testmenu.sub2"; ValueType: string; Flags: UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Testmenu.sub2"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "Sub menu 2"; Flags: deletevalue UninsDeleteKey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Testmenu.sub2\command"; ValueType: string; ValueData: ""; Flags: deletevalue UninsDeleteKey
```

The HKCR is inserted correctly (although this does not has a 64 section). But the HKLM is inserted at:

```
"SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Testmenu.sub2\command"
```

I also tried to prefix the Root to 'HKLM32' but that didn't work either.
If I create the HKLM keys manually, the menu works.

Ho1 can I insert the HKLM keys to in the given path or force it to 32-bit.

Comment: 64-bit Windows has 64-bit regedit, which [`shows 32-bit registry view in WoW6432Node`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097/en-us) redirection node. I assume that you run it and it misled you. Registry handling in Inno Setup is proven and works as described in docs.

Comment: Wow6432Node is the 32bit branch of the registry in 64bit system. If you need to input key in 64bit branch use `HKLM64` with `Flag: IsWin64` to avoid error on 32bit OSes

Comment: And your entry goes to Wow6432Node because your Setup runs in 32bit mode. If you would run your setup in 64bit mode (e.g. `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64`) then `HKLM` would be parsed as 64bit (not 32bit aka Wow6432Node).

Comment: Thank you both! I indeed was misled.

Comment: @TLama could you please turn this comment into a proper answer ?