# Inno Setup not creating registry entry in Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

I've got the following Inno Setup script:

```
#define MyAppName "MyApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "MyAppPublisher"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.myapppublisher.com"

[Setup]
AppId={{8D4D5A09-FD64-4C0F-94D9-19F22C827074}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf64}\MyCompany\MyApp
DefaultGroupName=MyCompany
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputDir=C:\tmp
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: ...

[Run]
Filename: ...
```

It doesn't do anything special. The [Files] and [Run] sections are quite standard. My program is installed fine and I can run it OK.

The problem is that when I go to **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`** I cannot see an entry with my AppId. I've checked **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`** just in case but it's not there either. I need to access that key to check if there is already an installation of my program. I've rebooted my PC but that didn't help.

There is an entry in "Control Panel - Uninstall a program" for my program.

I'm running:

- Windows 7
- Inno 5.5.5

Comment: It does. You are most probably having 64-bit version and looking in your regedit at the 64-bit view. Look into `Software/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall` in your regedit.

Comment: Thanks TLama. I was looking in the wrong place, the key is in Wow6432Node :)

Comment: You're welcome! I've explained this a few times. For instance [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426332/cannot-set-registry-insert-for-hklm-for-32-bit#comment32325133_21426332).